# Need suggestion about which microcontroller/processor and language to be used in my project

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am very new to robotics. but I will be writing algorithm for my robot to move around and gather information from its surroundings and process it. It will also process audio-visual signals. but I am in confusion about which micro-controller to use so it would be performance efficient and consumes less power.

The controller should also be capable of communication with wireless network (internet through wi-fi) and should also support memory integration.

Also I know to program in Java and C. please suggest which would be the best language to use for programming.

Thanks.

P.S. I would really like to use a microprocessor as it is highly customizable. Please suggest the best to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are the perfect candidate for the [Raspberry PI!](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/) It is an awesome microcomputer that can do plenty of things, has a great community of support and tons of add on boards that can do everything you might need including [driving motors for a robot](http://www.adafruit.com/product/2348)

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry Pi 2 will give you lot of options to play with in robotics field, ardunio would be nice addon with it. Another nice option would be ODROID , you can setup it up with ROS. 
Now regarding the language, C would be good.